# Trying to avoid rounding in double point arithmetic, unable to as double is exceeded

Tags: c++, double

I am trying to solve Project Euler 94 first with brute force.
This requires me to work out whether an area of a given triangle is integral.
I do know the base and height, which are both integral.

```
long double area = 0.5*h*b;
```

When using `double` point arithmetic I arrive at answers which exceeds the exponent and sacrifices the precision of the fraction.
Is there any way for me to to ignore most significant part of the exponent and solely focus on fraction as I am only interested in whether the area is integral and not what size it is. Also I am using Visual Studio which I believe does not have `long double` just `double`?

EDIT

This is my code now. It reduced number of wrong triangles picked up by 3 from 26 to 23.

EDIT 2

I have read everyone's suggestions, but I am still not able to filter out the heights which are not integral my latest code looks like this. I know I am doing something really stupid but just can't pin point it.

```
    void findAET(){

    int gt = 0; //triangle count is

    for(long long ss  = 3; ss<333333334;ss+=2){ //skips out odd bases
     for(int c = -1; c<2; c+=2){ 
      long long base = c + ss;      

        if((sqrt((ss*ss)-(double)((base/2)*(base/2)))) == int(sqrt(((ss*ss))-(double)((base/2)*(base/2)))) ){  // check if height is an integer

            if( (int)((sqrt((ss*ss)-(double)((base/2)*(base/2))))*base)%2==0){
                cout<<" same sides "<<ss<<" base "<< base <<endl;                       
                gt++;

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint, if the result is divisible by 2, one of the factors must be divisible by 2.

Comment: Generally if you want precise integer operations with large numbers, you should use [infinite-precision integers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/ints/cpp_int.html) (i.e. `boost::multiprecision::cpp_int`).

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with your function?  just check that `base  * height` is evenly divisible by 2?

Comment: I have done it (base*height)%2==0 , yet it still allows an options which are not valid eg 
base = 92604744
height = 80198051
area = 3713359590086716.711
to pass which has non itegral area. I guess there is conversion wrong somewhere but I can not pin point it.

Comment: How do you get a height of 80198051 when the base is 92604744 ??  If the base is 92604744, the height must be either 80198059.66 or 80198061.97  The caller to the code you showed must be computing height and not accurately enough.  If you post that code, someone might suggest a correction.

Comment: I assume you are using some kind of sqrt(double) to compute height.  The value whose sqrt you are taking is as large as a 60 bit integer, so you can't even represent the input to the sqrt perfectly.  You still ought to be able to convert the output from the sqrt to the nearest int (needing up to 30 bits) then square that.  Height is an int iff squaring the 30 bit int gives you the original 60 bit int.  (Assuming you correctly computed the input to the sqrt as a long long).

Comment: BTW, you don't ever care whether height is even.  If base is odd, then height is irrational, so you shouldn't even bother to try to compute height when bases is odd.  When base is even, you only care that height is an integer.

Comment: Your find_height function is good enough (not great).  You confused things with a typo in your comment.  Your base was 92604734, not 92604744.  The height then is super close to 80198051 but not exact.  So `ceil(height)==height` even though the correct height is not an integer.  You should compute the 64 bit int value of height squared (using x and y) and after computing the integer value of height see if squaring that gives you the right result.

Comment: JSF I do not know how I can square root and 64 int without having to type cast it to double or float

heightsq = ((ss*ss)-(base/2)*(base/2));
if(pow(sqrt(heightsq),2) ==  heightsq){}

Answer (score 4):

As was mentioned in the comments, if both`h` and `b` are both integer types, then `0.5*h*b` has an integer result if either `h` or `b` are even:

```
if (((h % 2) == 0) || ((b % 2) == 0)) {
    printf("area is integral\n");
} else {
    printf("area is not integral\n");
}
```

Comment: For fun, it could be written `if(h&b&1)` (testing for the "not integral" case).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately I am unable to verify whether a large square root is an int or not.

Answer (score 2):

If `(b * h) % 2 == 0` then we know that `(b * h) / 2` will be an integer result.  Then all you need is a integer data type.  I am not sure how big of a number you need to compute but a `long long` can hold up to `9223372036854775807` at 64 bits.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Returns zero if height is not an integer
// Returns exact height if there is an exact height 
// Relies on unsigned having at least 30 bits and long long at least 61
unsigned find_height( unsigned x, unsigned y){
    if ( y & 1 ) return 0;  // Height is not an integer because height squared is not
    long long hs = (long long)x*x - (long long)y*y/4;
    unsigned result = sqrt(hs) + .5;
    if ( (long long)result*result != hs ) return 0;
    return result;
}
```

If you compute height this way, you don't need any integer tests for area.  Area will be an integer whenever height is an integer.

With a 60 bit integer input, sqrt(double) is accurate enough that the closest integer will be the correct integer when the true answer is an integer.  But since a 60 bit integer can't really be held in a double, the test of whether the result of sqrt(double) is an integer can be incorrect in either direction from whether the true answer is an integer.  But it is trivial to find out whether the closest integer `(unsigned)(D+.5)` is the true answer, by just squaring it and comparing.

Comment: can't sqrt() of long long.

Comment: @mega_creamery everywhere I have done that (which is quite often with several different compilers) it has the intended behavior of implicitly casting the `long long` to double, then computing the sqrt.  When a 60 bit int has a int sqrt, the information lost in converting `long long` to double is regained by adding .5 and truncating.  When it doesn't have an int sqrt, that must be explicitly detected by multiplying.

Comment: If `hs` had been double, rather than needing to be implicitly cast to double, you would compute the same result of the sqrt more easily, but then you would have no good way to back test it to see if it was perfect.

Comment: If you have a compiler that complains about the two implicit casts in `unsigned result = sqrt(hs) + .5;` you can make them explicit with `unsigned result = (unsigned)(sqrt((double)hs) + .5);`